# angular-6-datatable multiselection rows

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-datatables

I am using angular-6-datatable in my angular project and wnt to select multiple rows. How to implement multi row selection on 'angular-6-datatable'. I have been searching on google from past 3-4 hours but did not get any post.

Comment: datatable is depricated.  You can use p-table for more flexibility and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

datatable is depricated in angular,  now new module is **p-table**, fallow the link, it will take you to the documentation.

```
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/table/export
```

If you want to go through only by datatable, fallow the link.

```
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/datatable/export
```

Below code is persuaded to **selection of rows** to export,  you can modify the below code in your required format.

```html
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedCars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="All Data" (click)="dt.exportCSV()" style="float:left"></button>
            <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file" iconPos="left" label="Selection Only" (click)="dt.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})" style="float:right"></button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```